# Basic Pointer Usage

Tags: c, memory, pointers, casting

I'm trying to write a function that takes a void pointer to an int and then doubles the int, and puts it back into the memory location:

```
void doubleNumber(void *number){
    number = &((*((int*)(number))) * 2);

}
```

So first I cast it into an int * from a void *, then I deference the int * to get the value, then I multiply by 2 and then I get the address of that to put it back into the pointer.

Can anyone give me tips on why my logic is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write it like this:

```
void doubleNumber(void *number){
    *(int*)number *= 2;
}
```

First of all cast `number` to be of type `int*`. Then dereference the pointer. Then double it.

The problem with your code is that you are assigning the pointer rather than the pointee.

Comment: Well, you were assigning to the pointer rather than the pointee. I think that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

```
void doubleNumber(int *value) {
    *value = 2 * (*value);
}
```

Step 2:

```
void doubleNumber(void *value) {
    int * ivalue = (int *)value;
    *ivalue = 2 * (*ivalue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A value (such as 2) has no address.

Instead, simply write:

```
* (*int)number = *(int*) number) * 2;
```

or, shorter:

```
* (*int)number *= 2;
```

Comment: You don't need to remember all of C's precedence rules, but one simple rule that's worth remembering is that the unary operators all have higher precedence than anything except the function call, array subscript and structure member access operators.  So `*(int *)number` will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, arguments to functions in C are passed by value, so modification of `number` will have no effect.

Secondly, even if it did, you should allocate some memory for the value first.  Only then can you return a pointer to this place in memory.